# Какое кэширование использовать для социальной сети?

Tags: база-данных, сервер, кэширование

Мы написали социальную сеть, в которую ожидается огромное количество посетителей. Мы решили использовать memory cache для нее. В нашей социальной сети мы используем комбинации серверов Windows и Linux. Память должна быть установлена ​​на Linux сервере.

Если у вас есть опыт работы с кэш-памятью, подскажите, пожалуйста, которая является лучшим выбором для такого типа задач? И еще что вы думаете о RADIS, MongoDB, Hibernate или Memcache?

Answer (score 6):

Вам надо сначала понять, сколько данных и какие данные вы хотите кешировать! Отсюда сразу станет ясно преимущества и недостатки того или иного решения.

Так как непонятно, что Вы хотите кешировать, то напишу от себя (проверено на редис):
все статичные шаблоны, используемые для генерирования динамических страниц и данных сложите в кеш (сократите на файловых операциях). Что касается базы данных, то какое бы вы решение ни выбрали, у вас туда войдут только справочники (неизменяемые или редко изменяемые), к примеру кладр, для выбора адреса. Ни в коем случае не ложите туда изменяемые данные или растущие от количества посетителей (уников). На этапе старта будете прыгать от счаться, а впоследствии все упадет мертвым грузом (головные боли, ночи программирования напролет и т.д.). Что еще можно положить (все то, что вешает базу и надолго, но опять же с учетом, что это не будет расти в памяти).

Все это легко объясняется, прочитав концепцию (на примере редис): все данные хранятся в памяти. А сколько у Вас памяти (8 гб или супер сервер 16 или распределенная сеть из нескольких серваков (16 или 8*количество серверов + широкий канал между ними))?

P.S.: Что касается redis: если Вы хотите использовать расширенный функционал по обработке данных, то несомненно его. Если просто key-value, то любой.

Comment: Позвольте пару вопросов: что такое редис, почему нельзя класть изменяемые данные в БД, и куда их тогда класть?

Comment: Речь наверно идет о часто изменяемых данных, но тем не менее я присоединяюсь к вопросу.

Comment: в XML чтоле? xDDD